# Error while setting segue programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segue, uibarbuttonitem

I've created a leftbarbuttonItem programmatically bacause I need that button to be bigger than standard barButtonItem. And I want that button to perform a segue that would push our view to next ViewController.

Here is what I've added to my ViewDidLoad function in my first ViewController:

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom) as UIButton
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Moroz.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 40)

        button.addTarget(self, action: "open", forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Here is the function "open" (I've placed it right after viewDidLoad ends, though I've tried to place it before and the result is still the same):

```
func open(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toexpress", sender: sender)
}
```

I've created a segue "toexpress" by ctrl dragging from first ViewController to second one. And the identifier I've given to it is obviously "toexpress".

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

But every time I run my app and click on my button I get

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException(lldb)
```

If I use standard barButtonItem everything works fine, but that's not an option because I need it to be bigger.

Can anyone point out where I've made my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: The action needs to be `open:` since the function takes an argument, `sender`

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks a lot!